# Disable SAML token authentication response digital signing

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, adfs, adfs2.0

Is it possible to disable digital signing for specific RP.
I do not see that option, maybe from shall ?

I need that for some testing purposes.

Environment : ADFS 2.0 , SAML 2.0 protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digital signing of what - the SAML token, the AuthN request ...?

In terms of the token - No - that would break security.

In terms, of the AuthN request, yes - it's an option in the AuthN request. However, for this to work you would have to liaise with your IDP. Both sides need to agree.

Comment: Yes, I mean on token signing.